# status code 400 when using CYLANCE OPTICS API

Tags: python, rest, security, antivirus

I'm trying to use the Cylance Optics API to isolate a device with the lockdown device function, however when executing the API query I get the feedback that the lockdown_type is necessary.

status code 400 with body b'{"status": "CLIENT_ERROR", "message": "'lockdown_type' is a required property"}

but the API documentation doesn't say how we should assign the lockdown_type in the request.
I'm using the demisto platform to develop this. Has anyone experienced this error and/or know how to resolve it?

request code:

```
def lockdown_device_request(device_id, value, expires):
 # Create request
 access_token = get_authentication_token([SCOPE_OPTICS_LOCKDOWN])
 headers = {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
 }

 
 uri = f'{URI_DEVICECOMMAND}/{device_id}/lockdown?value={value}&expires={expires}'

 res = api_call(uri=uri, method='put', headers=headers)
 return res
```

here is the api documentation, specifically on the part in question.
https://docs.blackberry.com/en/unified-endpoint-security/blackberry-ues/Cylance-API-user-guide/Device_Commands/Lockdown_Device_Command

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please properly indent your code. Invalid indentation is a syntax error in Python.

Comment: Remember to read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask): your title summarizes your question, it does not replace it: if there's an error, show the full error (_as text_) in your post. And of course remember to confirm trivial things like "am I even calling the correct version of the API" because who knows, you might not even be calling `v2`, we can't tell from this code.